# Combining two already working ORACLE queries

Tags: sql, oracle, nested

I'd like to ask for help with the two queries below. They work like a charm separately, now I want them to work together.

Both of them serve a loyalty card database.

The first one gets various information related to a user based on their unique cardnumber (**%1111%**, **%2222%**, **%3333%** in the example below) and returns the rows **in the custom order** that the cardnumbers were provided in.

```
SELECT cardnumber, first_name || ' ' || last_name 
FROM (
     SELECT cardnumber, first_name, last_name, c.OrderNo
     FROM ag_cardholder ch, (SELECT '%1111%' cardmask, 1 OrderNo from dual
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT '%2222%', 2 OrderNo from dual
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT '%3333%', 3 OrderNo from dual
                        ) c
     WHERE ch.cardnumber LIKE c.cardmask
     Order by c.OrderNo
) t
```

The second code returns the **current point balance** of a card based on the cardnumber and the type of the terminal last used to write the points on the card. There are **two types of terminals** that calculate the actual balance differently (one of them needs the number in the **balance** column, the other needs to **sum** the **balance and total_points** columns).

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT
cardnumber,
(SELECT last_name || ' ' || first_name FROM ag_cardholder WHERE cardnumber = '1111'),
CASE
WHEN terminal_id LIKE 'AGHUPR9%' THEN card_balance
WHEN terminal_id LIKE 'AGHUPR7%' THEN card_balance + total_points
END
FROM ag_tranzakcio
WHERE cardnumber = '1111'
ORDER BY tran_date DESC)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

**What I want** is a query that does both of these tasks: gets the cardnumbers in the provided order and returns some user information along with the current balance in the same order. Your help would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE:** Unfortunately I'm not familiar enough with ORACLE to come up with even a trial-and-error solution so I depend on your insight now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT cardnumber, name, balance, OrderNo
FROM
(
    SELECT 
    ch.cardnumber cardnumber, 
    ch.first_name || ' ' || ch.last_name name, 
    CASE WHEN t.terminal_id LIKE 'AGHUPR9%' THEN t.card_balance 
         WHEN t.terminal_id LIKE 'AGHUPR7%' THEN t.card_balance + t.total_points 
    END balance,
    rank () over (partition by ch.cardnumber order by t.tran_date DESC) rank,
    c.OrderNo as OrderNo
    FROM ag_cardholder ch
    JOIN (SELECT '%1111%' cardmask, 1 OrderNo from dual
                                UNION ALL
                                SELECT '%2222%', 2 OrderNo from dual
                                UNION ALL
                                SELECT '%3333%', 3 OrderNo from dual
                                ) c ON ch.cardnumber like c.cardmask
    JOIN ag_tranzakcio t ON ch.cardnumber = t.cardnumber 
)
WHERE rank = 1
ORDER BY OrderNo
```

EDIT: Assuming the ag_tranzakcio.id field is a reliable incrementing key, this could work:

```
SELECT cardnumber, name, balance, OrderNo
FROM
(
    SELECT 
    ch.cardnumber cardnumber, 
    ch.first_name || ' ' || ch.last_name name, 
    CASE WHEN t.terminal_id LIKE 'AGHUPR9%' THEN t.card_balance 
         WHEN t.terminal_id LIKE 'AGHUPR7%' THEN t.card_balance + t.total_points 
    END balance,
    rank () over (partition by ch.cardnumber order by t.id DESC) rank,
    c.OrderNo as OrderNo
    FROM ag_cardholder ch
    JOIN (SELECT '%1111%' cardmask, 1 OrderNo from dual
                                UNION ALL
                                SELECT '%2222%', 2 OrderNo from dual
                                UNION ALL
                                SELECT '%3333%', 3 OrderNo from dual
                                ) c ON ch.cardnumber like c.cardmask
    JOIN ag_tranzakcio t ON ch.cardnumber = t.cardnumber 
)
WHERE rank = 1
ORDER BY OrderNo
```

Comment: Thank you, StevieG, your solution is almost perfect. Unfortunately **MAX(tran_date)** sometimes returns multiple lines for each card as there are cases when the customer obtains points for various products at the same time (e.g. they buy a candy bar and a sandwich using the card once when paying, but we see this as two separate transactions in the database, one row for each product). This is why **ORDER BY tran_date DESC** along with **ROWNUM = 1** was used in the original. If you could help me out just a bit more telling me how to include this row limit, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a transaction id on the ag_tranzakcio table?

Comment: I do, but its order is very unreliable. At first I used it to order the transactions but then older transactions started popping up with the highest transaction IDs, so unfortunately it's not an option.

Comment: Thinking about it, I might have just screwed up something else when I last tried it. I'll revisit it in a few minutes.

Comment: Hmm, thats very strange.. I changed it to use the rank function, so not sure how multiple rows can come back, can you show me a pair of duplicates?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I ended up deleting all my comments from the last few minutes. I just tried to run the modified query, I get an invalid field name error for some reason. In the meantime I came to the conclusion that we can probably use the transaction ID to order after all, I was probably wrong about it being unreliable. If that's easier to implement, I'm happy with that, too. It's simply called **id**.

Comment: We're nearly there.. can you post the entire error text you got.

Comment: Sure. This is what I get. **Invalid field name. [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00904: invalid column name.** Please note that what I use and have access to is only some sort of a frontend to manage the database, so my toolkit is very limited when it comes to debugging.

Comment: Can it be because I have read-only permission? If so, it's something I won't be able to change.

Comment: It does now, but I still get multiple rows with some users. Here's an example. [link](http://i54.tinypic.com/4ky5xx.png)

Comment: can you add rank to the list of output fields.. I suspct if the dates are the same, they're both being ranked as 1. I dont suppose you have a tiestamp field on the ag_tranzakcio  record

Comment: I added the rank to the previous version before your last edit, the same dates get the same rank as you'd assumed. Unfortunately there's no timestamp to go with, either. I also tried your newest query, it works like a charm if I assume that the ID is reliable. It's not, but seems to fail very rarely. So in case the date version won't work, I'll be quite happy with the ID as well, just let me know if it can't be done with the date.

Answer (score 1):

The revised requirement is to return only the most recent transaction for each card.  This can be done by using the analytic function RANK() to sort the transactions, and then applying a wrapping query to filter on the calculated rank.

```
select cardnumber
       , card_holder
       , txn_amount
from 
    (
    SELECT ch.cardnumber
           , ch.first_name || ' ' || ch.last_name  as card_holder
           , CASE
                WHEN txn.terminal_id LIKE 'AGHUPR9%' THEN txn.card_balance
                WHEN txn.terminal_id LIKE 'AGHUPR7%' THEN txn.card_balance + txn.total_points
            END as txn_amount
           , rank () over (partition by ch.cardnumber order by txn.tran_date DESC) as rnk       
            , c.orderno
    FROM ag_cardholder ch
         join    (SELECT '%1111%' cardmask, 1 OrderNo from dual
                            UNION ALL
                            SELECT '%2222%', 2 OrderNo from dual
                            UNION ALL
                            SELECT '%3333%', 3 OrderNo from dual
                            ) c 
            on (ch.cardnumber LIKE c.cardmask)
         join ag_tranzakcio txn
            on (ch.cardnumber = txn.cardnumber)
    )        
where rnk=1       
order by orderno, cardnumber  
/
```

Comment: Thank you, APC, but unfortunately the query won't work indeed, and I'm not familiar enough with ORACLE/SQL to be able to debug. This is why I submitted the question in the first place. Thank you for your efforts anyway.

Comment: @Andrew - in what way doesn't the query work?  Compilation error?  Wrong results?  I'm not telepathic (and neither is anybody else on SO).  You need to give us details: describe the observed behaviour, including any error messages.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of details, I was in kind of a rush to try and tweak the query anyway so that I can come back with something helpful. Initially the query didn't run at all. I fixed two errors, on of them being a typo in txn.terminal_id where you wrote an underscore (_) instead of a dot (.), the other one being the slash at the end. This way I was able to run the query. It now returns all the transactions of the cards instead of just the last one. I probably just need to know where and how to limit the rows resulted per user.

Comment: @Andrew - The slash is not a typo, it is the standard delimiter for a SQL statement.  However, some clients don't recognise or need it.  By "the last one" you presumably mean the most recent transaction for each client.  That's quite easily done.

Comment: Thank you again for helping me out, you got what I meant by "the last one" right. However, this time I get an invalid field name error. My guess would be because your code tries to select card_balance and total_points from ag_cardholder, even though these fields are in ag_tranzakcio. (Also, there's a tiny typo with "partition" but fortunately that was something I could fix myself.) Your help fixing this problem would be really appreciated.

Comment: @Andrew - Not sure why you're getting "invalid field name".  I hadn't aliased the card_balance and total_points but that shouldn't have made any difference.  You should be getting a line number or some indication of where the problem is.  Unfortunately, without that info or the details of your schema there's nothing more I can do to help you.

Comment: Thank you, APC, for your help. The other answer I got in the meantime will probably solve the problem with way less troubleshooting, so I'd stick with that one instead, but I'm really grateful for your continuing effort.